# What is the simplest way to use a server to combine web page and python program?

Tags: javascript, python, html

Right now I have a Python file which takes in input and makes calls to a website's API based off of that input, and returns a csv file with the results.

I also have an HTML & JavaScript file which basically just consists of a search page that takes in the input that I want to feed into the Python program.

How do I go about linking these files so that the input on the web page will go into my Python file, and then come back out with the csv file?
I understand that I will be needing to use some kind of server, but I have no experience with servers and I'm not sure of the simplest way to go about this.

Comment: Your python file takes in the input from your javascript/html file?

Comment: You need a web server that hosts your python script and routes requests to it. Quick google comes back with this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html look at this too https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html

Comment: No, I want it to but I don't know how. Right now it just takes input from the keyboard.

Comment: @AdamH Warning: That's the Python 2 docs, so it's information is likely to be hideously outdated.

Comment: django? https://www.djangoproject.com/

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Maybe, I don't know Python so I've never had to look at any documentation but I'm sure the basic principals are still the same.

Comment: @AdamH The main problem is that Python 2 is full of what's now considered bad practice because there are better, more obvious ways to do it. Also, `print` is a keyword for some reason.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'll take your word for it, I don't use Python and don't plan on it. I was just trying to help out by showing the first example I found for setting up a web server with a Python backend.

Comment: @AdamH That's the fault of your search engine. That annoys me too.

Comment: It filters out "duplicate" pages, too, which means that the Python 3 version might never appear!

Comment: Hi Sam: Please be aware that right now there are two versions of Python widely in use: Python 2 and Python 3. Please specify which one you are using. This is the updated "simple server" for Python3 https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/http.server.html | I would advise maybe looking into a framework like Flask

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick, minimal, skeleton for your problem, made using flask, to help you get started.

You should add templating, parameter checking, response type headers - but this should point you into the right direction. Check the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/) for more.

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def form():
    return '<form action="/data"><input name="my_input" /><input type="submit"></form>'

@app.route("/data")
def process_form():
    user_input = request.args.get('my_input')
    csv_result = call_website_api(user_input)
    return csv_result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

If you install flask and run this code, it will start a server on port 5000. Go to http://localhost:5000 to access it.

You can change the `call_website_api()` line to `csv_result = "OK"` to be able to test the code and see it working, before adding your api call.